# MySQL выборка групп

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

[image: картина таблицы]

Исходные данные:

```
id;color;price
1;red;25
2;green;85
3;blue;2
4;black;20
5;green;96
6;red;18
7;black;5
8;black;10
9;green;14
10;blue;96
11;red;8
12;green;5
13;blue;14
14;black;26
15;blue;6
```

каким запросом получить по два минимальных значения каждого цвета? Ожидаемый результат запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Именно одним запросом хочется получить такой результат.

Comment: Вы бы прикрепили данные в каком нибудь виде, пригодном для копирования. В SQL например.

Comment: И показали бы, что уже пробовали.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` в CTE и потом `WHERE rn < 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант

```
select id, color, price
from colors
where price = (select min(price) from colors as X where X.color=colors.color)
or price=(select min(price) from colors as X where X.color=colors.color 
and price > (select min(price) from colors as Y where Y.color=colors.color))
order by color, price;
```

Или с меньшим числом подзапросов

```
select id, color, price
from colors
where (
   select count(*) from colors as X
   where X.color = colors.color and X.price <= colors.price
) <= 2
order by color, price;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  все получилось